# Emails sent under an alias do not pass SPF/DKIM authentication checks (commercial provider, not home server)

Tags: email, dkim, spf

For the past three month I have been attempting to migrate from one hosting company to another, and that includes mailboxes. Two hosting companies are active, the one I'm leaving, the one I recently subscribed to (Company 1 and Company 2). This subscription overlap wasn't intended; I expected a brief downtime as the DNS record is changed and propagated. At most, I would have expected to lose only a few incoming emails.

The reason I'm posting this here is the technical service from Company 2 doesn't appear to take the problem seriously, even going as far as suggesting me to contact the network administrators to ask them to add the company's own SMTP servers to their SPF records. I may not know much about email routing, but that's not how it's done. Now, before going any further, Company 2 used to be a highly respected hosting company for the past 25 years while Company 1 caters to more basic needs (no fancy tools) but equally knowledgeable.

Please excuse me if wording is imprecise, English is no my 1st language and network administration not my trade.

I'll try to illustrate as precisely as possible.

1. The **domain** itself is independently registered to a **registrar**. Although many hosting companies offer to transfer the domain name to them, I want it to remain independent. In the past, the registrar was one of the very few that had strict privacy protection.
2. The **DNS zone is at Company 1** since my Nextcloud is still there. The rationale being, if I can't make a basic function (email) work at Company 2, then I've got no reason to stay.
3. I have an email **adress under my own domain** at Company 2 (**address 1**). *The same address is also hosted at Company 1*. By setting up the priority in the MX record in the DNS zone, emails only went to the Company 2 mailbox. I since had to revert this setting since I still haven't solved the issue at hand.
4. Both hosting companies have **SPF and DKIM activated**, although in this scenario the SPF record in my own DNS zone doesn't play any role in deliverability.
5. I have another **address from a different domain** (academic) (**address 2**).
6. The academic address is **redirected to my personal one**.
7. Both mailboxes hosted at both companies are set up to use **address 2 as an alias**.
8. Company 1 uses a single SMTP server, Company 2 is much larger and uses a pool of SMTP servers (at least a dozen).

**What I want to achieve**: To be able to send emails from address 2 from a single mailbox, my personal one (aKa send emails under alias). A very common setup that greeatly simplifies day-to-day emails management, really. This has worked for years at Company 1, and before that at yet another hosting company, and before that two or three free email providers.

**Test setup**:

- A GMail address
- [DKIM Checker](https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/dkim/dkim-checker/)
- [DNS Checker.org](https://dnschecker.org/dkim-record-checker.php)
- [appmaildev](https://appmaildev.com/en/spf)
- A Yahoo! address used as an alias (**address 3**)

**What I did:**
I followed Company 2's instructions to add and authenticate external addresses. I did receive the authenticating email in my personal mailbox (as per the redirection from address 1), and thought all was good. Wrong.

**The result**:

1. For an unclear reason, GMail always rejects sent messages from the address 2 alias with a "SPF and DKIM both 550-5.7.26 do not pass" error.
2. I then tried with the Yahoo alias. In the same scenario, GMail throws a slighlty different "Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's 550-5.7.26 DMARC policy" error.
3. By comparison, emails sent directly from address 1 (either from Company 1 or Company 2) always get delivered.

I don't understand why the rejection reason differs from one alias to another, but proceeded on testing these records.

**Testing SPF**

As I'm not familiar with email deliverability subtleties, DNSChecker explained it in plain English:

> SPF record determines which email servers are authorized to send the email(s) on the domain's behalf (…)The receiving server then verifies the SPF record for all the IP addresses authorized to send an email(s) on behalf of the domain.

- Sending *under alias from Company 2* gives the **"SPF: neutral"** result.
- Sending *under alias from Company 1* gives the **"SPF: pass"**, explicitely telling the receiving server the email is valid.
- Sending *under address 1* (non-alias) from Company 2 gives the **"SPF: pass"** result.
- Finally, sending *under address 3 alias from Company 2* also gives **"SPF: neutral"** result.

By itself, the "neutral" result usually isn't enough to block an email. I understand the domain for address 2 merely tells the receiving GMail server the message may or may not be valid if it passes through Company 2 SMTP servers. Conversely, Company 2 SMTP servers are registered in the same SPF record as being allowed to send on behalf of their own email addresses, but not using any other alias.
By contrast, Company 1 SMTP server is considered valid in the SPF record to send emails from its own addresses as well as authenticated aliases from other domains.

**First question**: why would Company 2 SMTP servers not be registered as allowed to send on behalf of the other, authenticated email addresses?

**Testing DKIM**

From what I understood, an email is sent with a DKIM signature attached. This signature is generated from both the public key (in my DNS zone) and the private key (kept by the hosting company). Since my DNS zone is still at Company 1, I have two DKIM records, each with a different selector.

- Sending *under alias from Company 2* gives the "DKIM: none" result (no signature)
- Sending *under alias from Company 1* gives the "DKIM: pass", meaning the message is properly signed and valid.
- Sending *under address 1* (non-alias) from Company 2 gives the "DKIM: pass" result.
- Finally, sending *under address 3 alias from Company 2* also gives "DKIM: none".

I assumed that a signature isn't generated if one party doesn't sign its part of the message. It seems that Company 2 is not signing the emails that pass through them when it doesn't come from their own, hosted addresses.

**Second question**: why wouldn't Company 2 SMTP servers sign messages using their own private DKIM key?

Comment: Okay, I think it sounds like you need to configure DKIM for all the email domains you own in the SMTP outgoing server configuration that Company 2 allows you to maintain the DKIM records. I left a slew of comments, re-read your post, and most of that you already knew and I think it sounds like that may be the issue. The DKIM for EACH DOMAIN needs to be setup on the SMTP server the email address will send as or from. It sounds like the Company 2 needs the alias 2 and alias 3 email domains configured to DKIM sign those I think. I don't think you are using an internal email server after all.

Comment: Ask Company 2 to show you where to go to enable and configure DKIM signing for additional domains you own that your send email as or from domain wise. Be sure you have SPF DNS TXT record setup for each email domain as well though too. Ensure none are missed with either configuration.

Comment: So where you say "`Sending under alias from Company 2 gives the "DKIM: none" result (no signature)`" and "`Finally, sending under address 3 alias from Company 2 also gives "DKIM: none".`" get DKIM setup for those email domains on Company 2 email server. They should be able to tell you where/how to configure.

Comment: Please note: I don't own the domain at **address 2**, nor the one from **address 3**, therefore I can't add anything in there. I can readily use **address 2** as an alias to **address 3**. This has worked for years, and I own neither domain. 

As an example, even GMail provides [instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) to do so. No manual setting required.

Comment: So per the 'instructions' link, the section where you authenticate to an SMTP server, I suspect when you send an email FROM that address after you configure it, it then authenticates with that SMTP and then sends it out from that server. So perhaps that server has properly SPF and DKIM signing enabled. Can you ask the owner of address 2 and address 3 if they can enable DKIM message signing on their server for email it allows to send out from it (the SMTP servers)? I would also sent a slew of test emails to other gmail addresses with all the variations and then compare [cont]....

Comment: ...[cont] the message headers from the emails once you receive them. See if you can receive on a different personal account the one that fails to deliver when you send it from one address of the other, and inspect those message headers and use https://mha.azurewebsites.net/ to trace those out. The recipient email server that has the mailboxes that receive email also have to check SPF and DKIM so there can be differences what's allowed to be received on one server versus the other in that direction too. I'd start digging into message headers and using that tool to troubleshoot maybe.

Comment: So when you send as address 2 or address three to the mailbox address that gets those two DKIM errors, to me that means the server you sent that from does NOT DKIM sign messages it sends out, and the SMTP server receiving those emails does not pass the DKIM and SPK stuff it has defined. Hopefully message header analysis will help you narrow it down more. I'd just start picking it apart and using Gmail, Yahoo, etc. accounts to receive in case any of those allow and you see the message headers on it since you cannot on the servers those do not deliver for DKIM not being signed, etc.

Comment: So outbound DKIM is the server signing outbound messages, inbound DKIM checking it totally different policy that the outgoing signing. You can enable DKIM check inbound but not sign outbound or vice versa, You can trust other domain SPF records (and they can trust yours too) to trust their defined IP addresses, etc. in their SPF record. Not sure if that helps much but you may know all that already. In any event, there are different configuration based on direction inbound/outbound, etc.

Comment: All addresses sent from their original SMTP servers of course are properly signed. I didn't include that result since it was so obvious.
In case it wasn't clear: The **GMail address** isn't receiving messages sent under alias from Company 2, so there's no header to analyse. The messages get rejected *before* reaching the inbox, hence my use of third party tools. This is 100% reproductible using any GMail address as a recipient, meaning GMail probably has configured strict SPF and DKIM checking. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.]> that means the server you sent that from does NOT DKIM sign messages it sends out, and the SMTP server receiving those emails does not pass the DKIM and SPK stuff it has defined
Correct, one is the result given by the tools listed in "Test setup", the other is the error message received from GMail, hence my question: why Company 2 SMTP does **not** sign outgoing messages? [cont.]

Comment: [cont.]
FWIW: sending under alias **address 2** to **address 3** (Yahoo) mailbox through Company 2 SMTP *does* get delivered, but in the spam box. Header analysis still shows "SPF neutral" and "DKIM none". That still points to Company 2 SMTP, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe but I've not worked with a lot of email cloud providers like the configuration you describle. Sounds like you have 2 providers that give you mailboxes and allow you to point your owned domains and addresses to their servers. You are transferring your domain from one provider to the other. I would put both provider 1 and provider 2 IP/spf DNS records BOTH in your owned email domains SPF records. For an email to do be delivered or even bounce bounce with NDR details seems a bit strange. I wonder if the provider you are leaving is at fault, I'd focus on getting the new configuration [cont]

Comment: [cont.] working but put both providers IP addresses in your SPF records. I've triple look over all MX records, DNS records, etc. in both host provider systems and any other DNS external pointers you control. I'm not sure how the alias work so from gmail you can send as another non-gmail and vice versa, but the mailbox you send as must have to authenticate to where it's mailbox resides so I assume it sends from the send as aliases mailbox but I do not fully understand how this configuration works at the server level & email flow. Email stuck in outbound queue no DNR that never delivers or what?

Comment: When you change 'hosting providers' you are talking about email address and mailbox hosting providers, right? If you can tell me the name of the two hosting providers, I can read up on how each SMTP configuration works. Just tell me their names and which you are leaving and which you are going to. Let me get my head around that, then I can think about the alias stuff more and see if I can think of anything. I'm having a hard time understanding your config so I want to start with understanding your specific providers, I do NOT need your email address or domains, just the provider names.